# executing a python script on windows using java Runtime.exec

Tags: java, python, wmi

I have a python script that runs on windows and uses win32 extensions and WMI to get some information. If I run the script using the command line, it executes perfectly. But, if I try to run the same script using java Runtime.exec("python myscript.py") it seems to get blocked on the waitFor(). The code is like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python myscript.py");
int exitCode = p.waitFor();
```

If I try to use this same java code with some very simple python script like

```
print "hello world"
```

I get the exitCode to be 0, which means it works. Can I execute a python script that imports WMI library, using java Runtime.exec()?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One likely reason is that your IO buffers are full and need to be flushed, so try flushing both stdout and stderr from your Process in the java code ([example code](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html)).

Alternatively, you could try redirecting all output to NUL or a text file with one of the following arguments to exec:

```
cmd.exe /c python myscript.py > NUL 2>&1

cmd.exe /c python myscript.py > output.txt 2>&1
```